# rest-assured kotlin extension sends an empty body

Tags: kotlin, rest-assured

I'm using rest-assured 4.4.0 with Kotlin and this simple test fails:

```
Given {
  body("hello")
}
When {
  post("/endpoint/")
} Then {
  statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)
}
```

rest-assured is not sending the `body` with the request:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:52298/endpoint/
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

If I switch to the java-based API, the test passes:

```
given()
  .body("hello")
.`when`()
  .post("/endpoint")
.then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)
```

I couldn't find any open issue in rest-assured github repo related to this problem, I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you should raise an issue on github.

Comment: done: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1509

Answer (score 1):

Wrong formatting, the `When` block must be on the same line as the closing bracket of the `Given` block.

**WRONG**

```
Given {
  body("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")
}
When {
...
```

**RIGHT**

```
Given {
  body("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")
} When {
...
```